# How smart is C++ deque iterator

Tags: c++, stl, deque

Say I have a `std::deque<int> d`containing 100 values, from `0` to `99`. Given [the following](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/):

> Unlike vectors, deques are not guaranteed to store all its elements in
>   contiguous storage locations: accessing elements in a deque by
>   offsetting a pointer to another element causes undefined behavior.

It appears line below is not valid:

```
int invalidResult = *(d.begin() + 81); // might give me 81, but NOT GUARANTEED, right?
```

My question is this: **does an iterator take care of this**?

```
std::deque<int>::iterator it = d.begin();
int isThisValid = *(it + 81); // 81 every time? or does it result in undefined behavior?
```

At one point, I had thought that the iterator would handle any discontinuities in the underlying storage, but now I'm not so sure. Obviously, if you use `it++` 81 times, `*it` will give you `81` as a result.

Can someone say for sure?

For what it's worth, I am not using C++11.

Comment: Which part of "by offsetting a **pointer**" has anything to do with `d.begin() + 81`?

Comment: Are you asking if a deque iterator is random access? Yes. it is.

Comment: @KerrekSB So they are trying to say "don't take the address of an element and then offset from there"?

Comment: @kmort yes that's exactly what they're trying to say. The storage of a deque isn't contiguous, unlike a vector.

Comment: @kmort: Yes, that's what "pointer" commonly means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It appears line below is not valid:
>
> ```
> int invalidResult = *(d.begin() + 81); // might give me 81, but NOT GUARANTEED, right?
> ```

On the contrary. The statement is perfectly valid and the behaviour is guaranteed (assuming `d.size() >= 82`). This is because `std::deque::begin` returns an iterator, not a pointer, so the quoted rule does not apply.

> ```
> std::deque<int>::iterator it = d.begin();
> int isThisValid = *(it + 81); // 81 every time? or does it result in undefined behavior?
> ```

This is pretty much equivalent to the previous code, except you've used a named variable, instead of a temporary iterator. The behaviour is exactly the same.

---

Here is an example of what you may not do:

```
int* pointer = &d.front();
pointer[offset] = 42; // oops
```

Comment: Okay. I'm happy the iterators handle any discontinuities transparently. This means I've got to look elsewhere for the bug I'm seeing. Thanks!

Comment: You get even more guarantees from the iterator: `std::deque::begin()` currently (C++17) returns a `LegacyRandomAccessIterator` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) which means that `d.begin() + 81` is in `O(1)` (while calling `it++` 81 times is in `O(n)`) which can be a significant performance boost.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this reference here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) a [std::deque](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) provides a [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) which will certainly work according to your example.

```
std::deque<int>::iterator it = d.begin();
int isThisValid = *(it + 81); // will be fine assuming the deque is that large
```